# "as to + verb" vs "to + verb"

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

Are there any differences between these two forms? Example:

> 1. "It has been done so **as** + 
>      to make it easier for academics and other judges to
>      refer to a particular passage in a judicial decision."
> 2. "It has been done so + to make it easier..."

Source: P176, Letters to a Law Student by Nicholas McBride

Comment: @tchrist Why did you replace the *"prepositions"* tag with the *"conjunctions"* tag?

Comment: @tchrist Really? So, is that source http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/dick/tta/wc/conjunctions.htm on the level of a wikipedia page? By the way, why do they use "dick" in that path?

Comment: @tchrist That's a, er, real impressive page on *"conjunctions"*. Who is it written for? Linguistics students?

Comment: @tchrist Well, since you **insist**, lemme look here into a vetted grammar source, er, like the 2002 *CGEL*, and on page 727, they talk about ***"(a) PPs with clausal complements -- finite clauses or infinitivals"***, and provide the example [7.iv] *"He phoned everybody before the meeting [so as to be sure of a quorum]".* -- Now, that seems to support the OP's use of the *"prepositions"* tag. So, why don't you now tell us why it matters so much that you went to the trouble to replace the OP's *"prepositions"* tag with your *"conjunctions"* tag.

Comment: @tchrist Well, I cited from the 2002 reference grammar *CGEL*. Why isn't it good enough for you? It supports the OP's *"prepositions"* tag, so why did you remove it? Are you saying that you know the grammar of today's standard English better than do the authors of *CGEL*?

Comment: Can't you just have both tags, and be done with it?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Hey! Party-pooper! :D

Comment: @Mari-LouA That's sexist! :) . . . (though true)

Comment: Could you give us some more context please @LePressentiment? Your second example could be one of several constructions ...

Comment: @Araucaria Yes. Better now?

Answer (score 5):

## *In Short* (or *tl;dr*)

These all say the same thing (well, or *can* say the same thing; see below):

1. It has been [done **so as to**](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22done%20so%20as%20to%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) permit   air to circulate freely.
2. It has been [done **so to**](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22done%20so%20to%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) permit   air to circulate freely.
3. It has been [done **in order to**](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22done%in%20order%20to%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) permit   air to circulate freely.
4. It has been [done **to**](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22done%20to%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) permit   air to circulate freely.
5. It has been done **so (that)** air can circulate freely.

(The fifth shows an alternate version with a finite clause instead.)

Of the *to*-infinitives, the fourth is best because it is shortest; the earlier ones are padded yet say the same thing as number four does.

---

## *Ambiguity?*

In the second instance, *done so to [verb]*, an ambiguity exists that cannot be completely resolved without more context being given.  The first reading is given above, while the second reading equates these instead:

1. It has been **done   so             to permit**  air to circulate freely.
2. It has been **done   like that  to permit**  air to circulate freely.
3. It has been **done   that way  so that**      air can circulate freely.

### First Reading

In one reading, *so to* + infinitive is expressing simple purpose, just like *in order to* + infinitive does:

- We always lay a heavy log upon the hearth before we retire **so to have** hot embers awaiting us when we arise before dawn.
- We always lay a heavy log upon the hearth before we retire **so as to have** hot embers awaiting us when we arise before dawn.
- We always lay a heavy log upon the hearth before we retire **in order to have** hot embers awaiting us when we arise before dawn.

Or with *that* instead of *to*:

- We always lay a heavy log upon the hearth before we retire **in such a way that we will have** hot embers awaiting us when we arise before dawn.
- We always lay a heavy log upon the hearth before we retire. This **is done (so) that we (may) have** hot embers awaiting us when we arise before dawn.
- We always lay a heavy log upon the hearth before we retire **so that we (may) have** hot embers awaiting us when we arise before dawn.
- We always lay a heavy log upon the hearth before we retire **in order that we (may) have** hot embers awaiting us when we arise before dawn.
- We always lay a heavy log upon the hearth before we retire **that we (might/shall) have** hot embers awaiting us when we arise before dawn.

### Second Reading

However, an alternate way to read *so to* + infinitive interprets *so* to mean *thus* or *in this/that way*; that is, it refers back to the matter that has come previously, making for these equivalences:

- We always lay a heavy log upon the hearth before we retire.  We **do this to  have** hot embers awaiting us when we arise before dawn.
- We always lay a heavy log upon the hearth before we retire; **this way we have** hot embers awaiting us when we arise before dawn.
- We always lay a heavy log upon the hearth before we retire.  We **do so so that we may have** hot embers awaiting us when we arise before dawn.

---

## Documentation

In §VI of the OED2’s entry for ***so*** *adv.* and *conj.* (ɴᴏᴛᴇ ᴡɪᴛʜ ᴄᴀʀᴇ: the OED does **not** consider *so* to be a “preposition”!), the editors present the equivalence of the three conjunctions:

> **28. a.**    ***so··***, or ***so··as***, ***so as***, followed by an infinitive denoting result or consequence.

The monumental *An Historical Syntax of the English Language* by Fredericus Theodorus Visser from 1979 covers the use of ***the infinitive as an adverbial adjunct*** quite well.  [In §965 on page 1019 of Volume I](http://books.google.com/books?id=5aI3AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA1019&dq=%22so+to%22+-speak&hl=en&sa=X&ei=n96uU8rMMMinyATv2oDYCg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22so%20to%22%20-speak&f=false), Visser describes the type characterized by:

> 965 — *Type* ‘He had put on his globes *so as to be* ready’

> Here the infinitive is preceded by *so as to* (viz. without any words between *so* as in the preceding section). Whether the infinitive group expresses result or purpose is not in all the examples easy to ascertain, the line of demarcation between these two notions being often extremely vague.

> Occasionally the subject of the infinitive is expressed by inserting a (pro)noun beween *so as* and the *to* + infinitive.  In later Modern English this (pro)noun is preceded by *for* in this case: [. . .]

> There are a few examples of the use of *so to* instead of *so as to* to express result.  This idiom is now obsolete: [. . .]

As I read them, both the OED and Visser feel that the omission of *as* in *so (as) to* is now considered either ‘irregular’ (OED) or ‘obsolete’ (Visser) when expressing a result.  Whether they also consider the omission of *as* when expressing a purpose is not given.

I may not be reading something correctly here regarding obsolescence or irregularity. I say this because modern examples of (apparently) using *so to* to express purpose **can** be produced.  Here are a few that I believe qualify:

1. [We don't call “moving in” marriage, since it **is done so to intentionally avoid** the obligations of the marriage vows.](http://books.google.com/books?id=MC4zn0NbWoYC&pg=PA66&dq=%22is+done+so+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RNauU46PHcymyAT6_oGYDQ&ved=0CIkBEOgBMBM)
2. [Plundering and undermining **are done so to gain** wealth and to discredit the faith and spiritual vitality of the people.](http://books.google.com/books?id=AQO_ruL1t24C&pg=PA55&dq=%22are+done+so+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GdiuU_aDB4mnyATOt4CYBQ&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBw)
3. [Deceptions practiced **are done so to achieve** one or more of those goals.](http://books.google.com/books?id=Ij1FR-ogGYIC&pg=PA342&dq=%22are+done+so+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GdiuU_aDB4mnyATOt4CYBQ&ved=0CFsQ6AEwCw)
4. [And the lists that we then compile, **are done so to** respond to the specific requests of the person asking for the information. . . .](http://books.google.com/books?id=hREzDzXF7VwC&pg=PA75&dq=%22are+done+so+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GdiuU_aDB4mnyATOt4CYBQ&ved=0CHYQ6AEwEA)
5. [All the good works performed by the fraternity or sorority **were done so to** glorify Christ.](http://books.google.com/books?id=lJ0hFQlKx4oC&pg=PA233&dq=%22were+done+so+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=l9muU6bIGtGGyASy_YGgCA&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ)

To me, these modern examples suggest that using *so to* with the sense of *in order to* remains a viable reading.  It is for this reason that my *in brevis* abstract at the top of this posting equated the four versions that it did.

However, as Araucaria has kindly observed in comments, in at least some cases there may be wiggle room in deciding whether *so* is used anaphorically to refer back to the earlier part of the phrase.

---

## *Summary*

Contemporary readers, especially ones unfamiliar with “older” English literature (say, through the 19<sup>th</sup> century, the last such citation given by the OED or Visser), may fail to recognize the dual readings possible with *so to*, and therefore only ever see it as meaning *thus* or *in this way* combined with *in order to*.

But while the majority of the modern instances of *done so to* are using *so* to mean *in that way*, others do not.

The original question does not give enough context to give one short and simple answer that is also correct, and complete.

---

---

### *Postscript: Preposition or Conjunction?*

There has been some discussion in comments as to whether things like *so as* and *in order* are prepositions or conjunctions.  The answer, substantiated below from four documented sources, is that these are indeed conjunctions, albeit subordinating ones not coördinating ones.

To start with, both the *Oxford English Dictionary* and the *Oxford English Grammar* of 1996 maintain that constructions like *so as* and *in order* are ***subordinating conjunctions***, and that they can be followed either by non-finite verb clauses or by *that* and a normal subordinate clause.

From *Oxford English Grammar* of 1996 on page 158, with all italics in the original:

> Some subordinators are restricted to certain types of non-finite or verbless clauses: *for, in order to, in order for, so as, with, without*.

> [. . .]

> - [32]: I sometimes wonder whether Stephen actually went to prison *in order to have something to talk about when he came on this show*.

Next, this same position is also taken by Quirk’s *Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* of 1985, which on page 1004 reads as follows, with all emphasis in the original. The first and last sentences are the salient ones here:

> **14.17 Subordinators for *to*-infinitive clauses**
>
> *To*-infinitive clauses may be introduced by several subordinators: *as if, as though, for, in order, so as, whether . . . (or), with,* and *without*.  *For* in this function is restricted to infinitive clauses with their own subject, and indeed is often obligatory (*cf* 15.10):

> - It would be absurd idea *for them to move to another house at this state of their careers.*

> Since *for* may be combined with the subordinator *in order to*, it seems to be a device for introducing the subject rather than to be a true subordinator:

> - *In order for you to be eligible for a student grant*, you parents must receive less than a stipulated annual income.

> *Whether* (with or without correlative *or*) introduces a subordinate interrogative clause:

> - I don’t know *whether to put on the air-conditioning today.*

> In the absence of a subject in the subordinate clause, the subject is understood as identical with that of the matrix clause.

This shows that both Oxford and Cambridge include *so as* and *in order* among their list of ***subordinators*** (read, *subordinating conjunctions*), no matter whether these introduce a non-finite clause or a finite one.

As one final reference supporting this placement — and although I am rather shy about citing crowd-sourced material, particularly in the absence of duly footnoted references — I cannot help but observe that the [Wiktionary page listing English prepositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_prepositions) includes none with *so* in them.  They **do** of course include *as* there, too, while noting that *as* can also be an adverb or a conjunction — the selfsame categories into which *so* has traditionally fallen.

---

Apparently Messrs. Huddleston and Pullum have decided to reclassify subordinating conjunctions as prepositions when their argument is a non-finite verb clause but leave them as conjunctions when followed by a finite clause.

Makes no sense to me, but this would hardly be the first time I’ve caught Pullum barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Does needless verbosity include sesquipidelian phrases like "are but needless verbosity" ?

Comment: @Araucaria There ain’t no eighteen-inch words here, ma’am, just simple ones.

Comment: How long is verbosity?  :)

Comment: What, you want *froth* instead?  If I’m to strike out all words that from Rome to us have come, more than just that one will have to go before we’re done here.

Comment: Yes indeed :) but the "but" in this position might still be a bit padding-ish? Only playing, I liked your first response loads. But do you think that the first and last are really the same? For me the first could describe an accidental effect. The fourth is an infinitive of purpose, it means precisely that the reason it was done was to allow the air to circulate...

Comment: @Araucaria Well, I am interpreting those all as conjunctions, not as a mannerly adverb applying to *done*  which is then followed by a conjunction.  The original opposition was *so* versus *so as*, and in that instance, these both seem of the same cloth woven. If you want that *so* to mean *thus* or *that way* or *in such and such a fashion*, then that is something else again. But bar further guidance from the OQ, I’ve tried to answer what I thought he was asking without attempting a tortuous **rescue reading**.

Comment: I've had a look at your second link. I've trawled through the first ten pages, but I can't find any occurrence of ***done so to ...*** with this meaning. Could you give an example - one which clearly rules out ***so*** as the pro-form meaning *in this way*?

Comment: @Araucaria [“In other words, when the term 'scale' is used by social scientists it **is done so to indicate** an established state of affairs, a foundation, a given, an unquestionable framework from which one can subsequently begin to account for what is happening in a given situation.”](http://books.google.com/books?id=mOZMX4G-nX0C&pg=PA75&dq=%22is+done+so+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RNauU46PHcymyAT6_oGYDQ&ved=0CGUQ6AEwDA#v=onepage&q=%22is%20done%20so%20to%22&f=false)

Comment: Thanks for the examples, which are interesting. However, I think that all of these are passive forms which include the pro-form *so* in their verb phrase. For example, in the first, the previous clause is in the passive and so the pro-form occurs as the complement of passivised ***DO***. To make it clearer, were it active it would read ***when social scientists use the terms 'scale', they do so to indicate...*** Here ***so*** is clearly anaphoric, it is not part of a complex ***so to*** construction. It means they do *this thus* in order to ... No?

Comment: Nice post, though I'd point out that you missed out Visser's comment ***"now obsolete"***!!! The first example he gives is 500 years old, the second only 210. If you read the example, it's clear that this doesn’t in fact mean "with the purpose of" or "in order to", but rather "with the effect of". More precisely, the *so* in Visser's example clearly indicates something like *in this way*, *in this manner* or *thus*: ***It [giddiness of head] increased upon me to an alarming degree, so to render me incapable of moving from my seat***. (thus rendering me incapable) à la Neil above! –

Comment: @Araucaria I didn’t miss it: indeed, I specifically stated that Visser called that usage ‘obsolete’. I’ve now updated the post to place Visser’s remark *in situ*; I put it afterwards because I wanted to join Oxford and Visser with one remark. ¶ However, I agree that something isn’t matching up here, but I’m not quite sure what it is.  Clearly modern examples can be found that use *so to* in the *so as to* sense, which as you said is just a *to*-infinitive of purpose.

Comment: You said: "Next, this same position is also taken by *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* of 2006, which on page 1006 reads as follows, with all emphasis in the original." -- Er, say what? You sure you got the right reference grammar there? I've found your excerpt in the older 1985 reference grammar by Quirk et al., ***A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language***, section 14.17, page 1004. You might want to also cite from the more recent 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., because, well, it is more recent.

Comment: @F.E. Perhaps you should actually post an answer instead of arguing in comments: that way you can be subject to a vote of confidence.

Comment: Perhaps you should re-read your own posts and stop making those kind of errors. And, you are welcome that I pointed out that error, or would you rather that no one pointed out that error to you? Anyone who's read the 2002 CGEL would know right away that excerpt was bogus. And why would I want, or need, a vote of confidence, and from whom? Also, notice that I wasn't "arguing" with you in my previous comment--you were being corrected as to the bogus and misleading info you had put into your post.

Answer (score 5):

Yes they are different

"*It was done **so as to** make it easier.*" could be expressed as:

"*It was done **in order to** make it easier.*" or as
"*It was done **to** make it easier.*"

While "*It was done **so** to make it easier.*" could be expressed as:

"*It was done **in that manner** to make it easier.*"

You could combine both with "*It was done so, so as to make it easier.*"

Comment: Differences were asked for, a difference was given.

Comment: Very well then. Edit your post somehow to amplify that thought or make it look tidier or fix the missing punctuation, and I’ll retract my down vote.

Comment: On the button - succinct and helpful for the Original Poster and other readers ...  like me!   :)

Comment: -1 *so* is also very commonly used for *so that* and *so as to* esp., in conversation/ informal writing.

Comment: It is true that the sentence could be interpreted with *so* in the sense of *a certain way (of doing)* but that's not the case in the instant sentence.

Comment: I don't see how you can possibly conclude that from the fragment provided.

Comment: @Kris Re first response: OK, this aside is part true, but it has nothing to do with the question. There is no inquiry about *so that* in the question. What is your comment about *so as to* meant to add here? It's completely superfluous, it was addressed in the answer!!!

Comment: @Kris Re second response: Can you find any instance of an occurrence of *done so to ...* on for example Google Books, where it has the meaning *in order to*. I doubt it very much - because it wouldn't be grammatical. You will only find examples with the proform ***so***, meaning *thus* or *in this manner*, er, as explained perfectly well in this answer!!

Comment: @Araucaria I’ve now found you a half-dozen instances where *done so to [verb]* is used in a way that means the same thing as dropping the *so* altogether, or swapping in *in order* in its place.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks for the examples, which are interesting. However, I think that all of these are passive forms which include the pro-form *so* in their verb phrase. For example, in the first, the previous clause is in the passive and so the pro-form occurs as the modifier of passivised ***DO***. To make it clearer, were it active it would read ***when social scientists use the terms 'scale', they do so to indicate...*** Here ***so*** is clearly anaphoric, it is not part of a complex ***so to*** construction. It means they do *this/in this way* in order to ...

Comment: @Araucaria Suggest read your comments to find answers within.